# Refresing the page on (submit) process Angular2 & Firebase

Tags: html, angular, firebase, angular2-routing

I´m trying to apply Firebase to the [Admin HTML template](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-admin/) that I found yesterday.

In the register page when I click on Sign in it reload the page instead of do the Firebase `createUserWithEmailAndPass` process.

**This is my HTML code:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="registrar(form.value)" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (!name.valid && name.touched), 'has-success': (name.valid && name.touched)}">
    <label for="inputName3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input [formControl]="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName3" placeholder="Nombre completo">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (!email.valid && email.touched), 'has-success': (email.valid && email.touched)}">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">NIF</label>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input [formControl]="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="NIF/DNI">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (!password.valid && password.touched), 'has-success': (password.valid && password.touched)}">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contraseña</label>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input [formControl]="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Introduce una contraseña">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row" [ngClass]="{'has-error': (!repeatPassword.valid && repeatPassword.touched), 'has-success': (repeatPassword.valid && repeatPassword.touched)}">
    <label for="inputPassword4" class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input [formControl]="repeatPassword" type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Repite la contraseña">
      <span *ngIf="!passwords.valid && (password.touched || repeatPassword.touched)" class="help-block sub-little-text">Las contraseñas no coinciden.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
      <button [disabled]="!form.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-auth">Confirmar registro</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**And this my functions:**

```ts
nuevoUsuario(email, password) {
        console.log(email);
        return this.af.auth.createUser({
            email: email,
            password: password
        });
 }

public registrar(datos: Object): void {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.form.valid) {
      // your code goes here
     const formarCorreo = this.email.value +' @maimona.com';
      console.log(formarCorreo);
       
   this.afService.nuevoUsuario(formarCorreo.toLowerCase, 
       this.password).then((user) => {
          this.afService.saveUserInfoFromForm(formarCorreo.toLowerCase, 
         this.name, this.email).then(() => {
           // this.router.navigate(['login']);
         })
           .catch((error) => {
             this.error = error;
             console.log(error);
           });
       })
         .catch((error) => {
           this.error = error;
           console.log(error);
         });
    }
}
```

I don´t know why when I press "Confirmar registro" it reload the page instead of do the function. Well it enter the function until

```ts
console.log(formarCorreo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the type of the button to `button` from `submit` and add the function to the buttons click

```
<button [disabled]="!form.valid" class="btn btn-default btn-auth"
type="button" <-- type
(click)="registrar(form.value)" <--click
>Confirmar registro</button>
```

`type="submit` will make elements to reload the form

Comment: This is not enough since most of the time you'll want the "submit" feel of things, for example hitting the enter key.

Comment: @echonax what? :)

Comment: @echonax - I was actually wrong about this one - sorry. The problem I was talking about is when having a button inside a form *without* a type (not explicitly `type=submit`, IE will still post the the form. Setting it to `type=button` actually does work like you said. Sorry about that, I'll remove my comment!

Answer (score 2):

By default, html `<form>` elements navigate to their `target` attribute.

To override this (since this is what you'll want most of the time in a single-page app), angular provides the `(ngSubmit)` convenience event (which uses `event.preventDefault()`, which would solve your case anyway, but is cleanear)

Answer (score 0):

`<button type="submit">` is doing HTTP request to the server. It's the same like `<input type="submit">`.

You can change it to ordinary `<button>` or prevent the submitting a form using events.